# ODBC Login Failed for Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, odbc

I have a win10 Pro 64-bit OS.

I've installed Oracle SQL Developer v20.2.0.175

I created a PDB named PTU and added a DBA user named jsweeney with a mixed case password. I am able to connect to the database with that user in SQL Developer.

I set up a 64-bit ODBC connection using localhost:1521/PTU for the TNS Service Name. When I test the connection, I get the following error:

Unable to connect
SQLState=28000
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01017: invalid username/password; login denied.

I've tried:
all upper case for both username and password
all lower case for both
lower case for username and upper for password
lower case for username and mixed case for password

Any suggestions will a be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you sure you are connecting to the correct db?

Comment: "I am able to connect to the database with that user in SQL Developer."

Comment: Which ODBC driver do you use?

Comment: Check the account status. It may get (temporary) locked when you enter wrong password to many times.

Comment: Wernfried - I'm using the Oracle 18.0.9 instant client. I thought the account might be getting locked so I've been frequently running an unlock script in SQL Developer.